# How to disable autoplay from embedded Tiktok?

Tags: html, iframe, autoplay, tiktok

Strangely, when height of iframe is smaller than height of video, a button play appear, but when height of iframe is adjusted to height of video to prevent scrollbar, play button disappear and autoplay enabled (video plays automatically).

To see the problem, stretch the preview window:
https://codepen.io/pen/ZEjBEXZ

```
<iframe
    title="tiktok"
    src="https://tiktok.com/embed/7178944999692979502"
    style="
        border: 0;
        /* height: 578px; */    /* autoplay disabled, play button appear */
        height: 724px;          /* autoplay enabled, play button disappear */
    "
></iframe>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with your mentioned code. I tried this code on my existing project and the play button appears on both heights.
Maybe some other code in your project messes up with the iframes.

Comment: I added an example of the problem. To see it, stretch the preview window: https://codepen.io/pen/ZEjBEXZ

Comment: I tried a lot of things to prevent the stoping of autoplay but none of the solutions worked for the TikTok video. So Maybe the TikTok autoplay their videos when It's comes to the mobile screens,